# How to create an array of string type with some clear values?

Tags: typescript

Here's my code

```js
type SearchSchemaValue =
    | 'tagName'
    | 'textContent'
    | 'attributes'
    | 'attributes.id'
    | 'attributes.class'
    | 'attributes.style';

export type SearchSchema = (SearchSchemaValue | string)[];
```

If I type `const schema: SearchSchema = ['` I expect my IDE to suggest the values from `SearchSchemaValue`, but it doesn't; `SearchSchema` is considered `string[]` in the end.

How do you make this type: an array of string with possible values from `SearchSchemaValue`?

Comment: As you've seen, `narrower_type | broader_type` is simplified to `broader_type`, because that already allows `narrower_type`. You're left with `string[]`, which can't autocomplete. String literal types are only useful when other arbitrary strings _aren't_ valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an loose auto complete

```
type SearchSchemaValue = LooseAutoComplete<'tagName' | 'textContent' | 'attributes' | 'attributes.id' | 'attributes.class' | 'attributes.style'>
  

type LooseAutoComplete<T extends string> = T | Omit<string, T>


export type SearchSchema = SearchSchemaValue[];


let k: SearchSchema = ["test", "tagName"]
```

Resource: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_m7jxrTlaw&list=PLIvujZeVDLMx040-j1W4WFs1BxuTGdI_b&index=3

Comment: Thanks true hero :)